# getLoadedProductCollection doesn't have any products in it

Tags: category

After some hours I'm unable to list the products in categories. (the products are set correctly, 100% sure)

When I access a product direct by typing it's URL (or search) it goes just fine. But somehow the `getLoadedProductCollection` is always empty.

Comment: Might be stating the obvious here but did you reindex and clear cache?

Comment: @SanderMangel Haha, thanks, but yes, the strange thing is that the "getLoadedProductCollection" is empty. I simply can not find the answer :-S all the other things are working (search, flat tables etc)

Comment: Try and turn off all 3th party extensions, especially those for layared navigation etc, clear cache, reindex and try again. Sounds like a third party extension is messing it up

Comment: did you solve your problem I have the same! in one store I have them and another store I don't have them

Comment: Nope sorry, never finished it... I've just created a fix, but that's not near the correct answer.